# Equivalente in Postgres to the MySql sentence GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ‘%’@’%’ REQUIRE SSL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, ssl

Hi I need to know if there is an equivalent sentence in `Postgres` to the following `MySql` sentence:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ‘%’@’%’ REQUIRE SSL
```

I want that all the users connect to the database right through `SSL` connections.

Thanks

Comment: This is what you have to configure in pg_hba.conf

Comment: Thanks I will search how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permission themselves (via [`GRANT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html)) in PostgreSQL don't take into account how the role was authenticated. Authentication is configured in [`pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) instead.

You'll still need to use `GRANT`, simply to give access to that role on the tables, schema, views, etc., as required by your application.

If you want to grant access only when SSL is used, use `hostssl` instead of `host` in `pg_hba.conf`. (`host` is effectively `hostssl` or `hostnossl`.)

Note that, like HTTP redirections from HTTP to HTTPS, this security measure used on its own only really protects against passive attackers at best. Otherwise, MITM attackers could intercept the plain-text connection and forward it themselves to your server using SSL. The server wouldn't know about it (unless client certificates are used).

As always, what you need is to make sure that your client know that they need to use SSL, and that they verify the server certificate correctly. More specifically, if they're using a tool that relies on `libpq`, they need to configure your CA certificate (or your server certificate directly) correctly and use [`verify-full`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-ssl.html), to prevent MITM attacks.

Comment: Thanks, good answer. Do you know some documentation to do this using Amazon aws RDS??

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure whether Amazon AWS RDS gives you access to `pg_hba.conf` (or equivalent settings through some admin panel).